# Operaciones con Byte en Java - Duda Explicación de estos métodos

Tags: java, array, método, binario, byte

Me encuentro realizando un curso de Java y me piden que explique con algún ejemplo qué hacen ambos métodos y estoy un poco atascado.

Los métodos son los siguientes:

```
public void metodo1(int p1, boolean p2, int p3, int size) {
    byte[] byte_array;
    byte_array = new byte[size];
    if (p2) {
        byte_array[p1] = (byte) p3;
        byte_array[p1 + 1] = (byte) (p3 >> 8);
        byte_array[p1 + 2] = (byte) (p3 >> 16);
        byte_array[p1 + 3] = (byte) (p3 >> 24);
    } else {
        byte_array[p1] = (byte) (p3 >> 24);
        byte_array[p1 + 1] = (byte) (p3 >> 16);
        byte_array[p1 + 2] = (byte) (p3 >> 8);
        byte_array[p1 + 3] = (byte) p3;
    }

}
```

Lo que entiendo que hace es guardar en un array de bytes el parámetro 3 realizando diferentes transformaciones. Si el p2 es true lo que hace es ir guardando el p3 dejándolo tal cual, dividiéndolo entre 2^8, entre 2^16 y 2^24 pero al hacer un casting a byte, los valores corresponderán entre -128 y 127. En el caso de que p2 sea falso lo que hace es guardar en orden inverso pero esta vez multiplicando por 2^24, 2^16, 2^8 y dejándolo tal cual, todo haciendo casting a (byte). No le termino de encontrar el sentido a este método y más siendo void y no devolviendo nada.

```
public static boolean metodo2(byte p1, byte p2) {
    if (p2 > -1 && p2 < 8) {
        byte[] byte_array = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, (byte) 128 };
        if ((p1 & byte_array[p2]) == byte_array[p2])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

En cuanto a este segundo método, entiendo que devuelve true si p1 está dentro del rango siguiente de 2^p2. Por ejemplo, si pones p1=64 y p2=6 te da true porque al hacer la operación & entre 64 y 64 te da 64, lo cual es igual que lo que está dentro de esa posición del array. Mismo caso si pones un valor entre 64 y 127, que es el rango que hay entre 2^5 y 2^7, que son las posiciones anterior y posterior del byte array. Entiendo el funcionamiento pero no se me ocurre un ejemplo lógico y sencillo con el que poder explicarlo, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Método 1

Lo que hace `metodo1` es básicamente almacenar los bytes de un entero en formato big endian o little endian según el argumento `p2` dentro de un arreglo, que concuerdo contigo, no sirve de nada pues el arreglo no se retorna y no hace nada más ese método. Checa este link de Wikipedia para saber más sobre [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Recuerda que un `int` (en la mayoría de arquitecturas) tiene 32 bits o 4 bytes. Si queremos guardar esos 4 bytes en un arreglo de bytes, hay que escribir un código muy similar al que presentaste. La cosa es en qué orden lo guardas.

En tú código **el endianness lo determina el parámetro `p2`**, un nombre muy explicativo.

#### Little endian

Asumiendo que `p2 = true`

Little endian es el formato que guarda el bit más significativo (MSB, *Most Significant Bit*) al final.

Si tenemos un `int` con valor `7F FF 00 F2` (supongamos que es el valor de `p3`), se guardaría en el arreglo de bytes como `F2 00 FF 7F`. Para eso tomamos cada byte del arreglo

1. El primer byte lo tomamos con el casteo directamente `(byte) (0x7FFF00F2) = 0xF2`. Recuerda que se toma el primer byte.
2. Para el segundo hay que recorrer los bytes 1 byte (8 bits por eso `>> 8`) a la derecha `(byte) (0x7FFF00F2 >> 8) = (byte) (0x007FFF00) = 0x00`
3. Recorrer los bytes 2 bytes a la derecha `(byte) (0x7FFF00F2 >> 16) = (byte) (0x00007FFF) = 0xFF`
4. Recorrer los bytes 3 bytes a la derecha `(byte) (0x7FFF00F2 >> 24) = (byte) (0x0000007F) = 0x7F`

Con esos números ya obtenidos nada más los guardas en el arreglo de forma consecutiva como se muestra en el código

##### Nota curiosa / histórica

Este endianness es el que se prefirió utilizar en un inicio por varias computadoras debido al rápido acceso a la información. Pues si por ejemplo, se le pedía al procesador sumar dos números `0B B2` y `00 5F` (big endian), el procesador los guarda como `B2 0B` y `5F 00` para leer solo los bytes necesarios. Primero leería y sumaría los primeros bytes `B2` y `5F`, y de ser necesario (si hay acarreo) continuaría la suma con los siguientes bytes.

A diferencia de que si los guarda como `0B B2` y `00 5F`, en cuyo caso tendría que leer todos los bytes del número para poder realizar la operación (lo cual no es tan óptimo). Sin embargo actualmente eso no hace mucha diferencia en realidad.

#### Big endian

Es prácticamente lo mismo pero en diferente orden.

Asumiendo que `p2 = false`

Big endian es el formato que guarda el bit más significativo (MSB, *Most Significant Bit*) al principio.

Si tenemos un `int` con valor `7F FF 00 F2` (supongamos que es el valor de `p3`), se guardaría en el arreglo de bytes como `7F FF 00 F2`. Para eso tomamos cada byte del arreglo

1. Recorrer los bytes 3 bytes a la derecha `(byte) (0x7FFF00F2 >> 24) = (byte) (0x0000007F) = 0x7F`
2. Recorrer los bytes 2 bytes a la derecha `(byte) (0x7FFF00F2 >> 16) = (byte) (0x00007FFF) = 0xFF`
3. Recorrer los bytes 1 byte a la derecha `(byte) (0x7FFF00F2 >> 8) = (byte) (0x007FFF00) = 0x00`
4. Basta con el casteo `(byte) (0x7FFF00F2) = 0xF2`.

### Uso práctico

No se me ocurre otro ejemplo práctico mas que el siguiente, aunque se podría hacer mucho más sencillo.

Es simplemente checar si el número es o no negativo. Se podría hacer algo similar para checar si es par o impar.

```
if ((p2 && (byte_array[p1 + 3] & 0x80 == 0x80)) /* little endian */
    || (!p2 && (byte_array[p1] & 0x80 == 0x80)) /* big endian */)
    System.out.println("Es negativo");
```

Otro caso práctico podría ser si suponemos que es una IPv4, ahí podríamos decir de qué clase es y otras cosas.

### Método 2

Este método nada más te dice si `p1` pasa o no la máscara `1 << p2` con el operador `&` (definamos pasar la máscara como retornar el mismo valor de la máscara).

Eso lo puedes verificar con la siguiente implementación

```
public static boolean mask(byte number, byte m) {
    if (m < 0 || m > 7)
        return false;

    return (number & (1 << m)) == (1 << m);
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    for (byte exp = 0; exp < 8; ++exp)
        for (byte i = Byte.MIN_VALUE; i < Byte.MAX_VALUE; ++i)
            if (mask(i, exp) != metodo2(i, exp))
                System.err.println("mask != metodo2");

    for (byte exp = 0; exp < 8; ++exp)
        if (mask((byte) 127, exp) != metodo2((byte) 127, exp))
            System.err.println("mask != metodo2");
}
```

#### Uso práctico

Un uso práctico (pero nuevamente, no eficiente) podría ser por ejemplo contar el número de bits = 1 que tiene un número

```
byte i = 8;
byte j = 0;
byte k = ~0x00;
while (--i >= 0) if (metodo2(k, i) && (++j > 0));
System.out.println(j);
```

Compliqué el código anterior solo por ejercicio mental, y para dar un ejemplo de porqué no es buena idea tener variables con nombres no explicativos.

En fin, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación tan detallada y rica en ejemplos. Si es verdad que la explicación del método1 está muy condicionada a que size=4 y p1=0 para que comience el array en esa posición, igualmente no parecen muy de utilidad esos parámetros y les podían haber asignado un valor fijo dentro del método. Lo de los nombres no explicativos supongo que lo harán para no dar pistas. Saludos!